# Vertical text in table header?

Tags: text-alignment, itext7

How to make single header text (header of table) flow vertically instead of horizontal?

I tried adding

```
setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP)
```

I don't see it making any difference.

```
targetTable.addHeaderCell(new Paragraph("VerticalAlignment").setFont(myFont).setFontColor(ColorConstants.BLACK)).setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.TOP));
```

[image: see second and third column header text alignment]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "flow vertically"?

Comment: Hi @mkl see image.

Comment: Ah, not like a vertical font but rotated by 90°. Tomorrow...

Comment: user648026, does my answer provide the information you needed? Or do you still have issues creating vertical text in headers?

Comment: I didn't try it as i had other issues, i will try it soon, thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Comment: Ah, ok. If you run into problems, simply ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment, this is not a matter of *vertical alignment* (well, not primarily, we'll use the vertical alignment to vertically adjust the text in the outer header cells) but instead of *rotated text*.

You can create a table like in your image like this:

```java
ISplitCharacters noSplit = (text, glyphPos) -> false;

Table table = new Table(4);

table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("First Col Header"))
                              .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM));
table.addHeaderCell(new Paragraph("Second Column Header")
                              .setRotationAngle(Math.PI / 2).setSplitCharacters(noSplit));
table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Third Column Header").setRotationAngle(Math.PI / 2)
                              .setSplitCharacters(noSplit)).setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM));
table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Fourth Column Header"))
                              .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM));

table.addCell("Row 1 Description");
table.addCell("12");
table.addCell("15");
table.addCell("27");

table.addCell("Row 2 Description");
table.addCell("25");
table.addCell("12");
table.addCell("37");

table.addCell("Sum");
table.addCell("37");
table.addCell("27");
table.addCell("64");

doc.add(table);
```

*([CreateTableWithRotatedHeader](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/CreateTableWithRotatedHeader.java#L41) test `testCreateTableForUser648026`)*

To get the rotated text we apply `setRotationAngle(Math.PI / 2)` to the paragraphs in question.

To prevent the rotated text to be split across multiple lines, we discourage splitting  applying `setSplitCharacters(noSplit)`.

To have the column texts to be at the bottom of the header cells, not at the (default) top, we apply `setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM)` to the cells.

The result:

[image: Screen shot]